# problems with this TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' in pycharm django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm trying to save a query in the python shell in the terminal but it seems an error popped up saying this

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'self'

I've no idea what to do. I'm trying to type this `post.save()` but the error above showed up after I pressed enter. All I am trying is to type this

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
>>> from blog.models import Post 
>>> user = User.objects.get(username='user') 
>>> Post.objects.create(title='One more post', ... slug='one-more-post', ... body='Post body/', ... author=user)
<Post: One more post> 
>>> Post.save()
```

in the terminal

I've already tried searching for the same problems that others are facing but none of it matches my problem. all of the codes in the models and the admin were correct.

I've tried several websites and search for several problems that others have issues with but I couldn't find a solution for it.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post (models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),

    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               related_name='blog_posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default='draft')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title.


from Django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'author', 'publish',
                    'status')
    list_filter = ('status', 'created', 'publish', 'author')
    search_fields = ('title', 'body')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    raw_id_fields = ('author',)
    date_hierarchy = 'publish'
    ordering = ['status', 'publish']


admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

Comment: it's not clear in your example, when you create the post, did you assign it to the variable `post` or  are you calling `Post.save()` ?

Comment: Please show the *actual* code you typed in the terminal.

Comment: '>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import 
User
>>> from blog.models import Post
>>> user = User.objects.get(username='user')
>>> Post.objects.create(title='One more post',
...                 slug='one-more-post',
...                 body='Post body/',
...                 author=user)
<Post: One more post>
>>> Post.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' '
all i typed in the terminal/shell.py is this and the traceback was the error above.

Comment: I did assign post in the admin.py and I did use this 'from .models import Post'

Comment: I updated the post with the code you pasted in the comment, next time please do that directly.

Comment: I'm practising to code in python using this [https://www.academia.edu/27920477/Django_by_Example] but the problem is in "creating Objects" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `save` directly on the Post model. That's not what you want to do. 
Normally you would call it on the Post instance that you created, but you actually *do not need to save it at all* because `create` already did that for you.

I suspect what you thought you were doing was this:

```
post = Post(title='One more post', ... slug='one-more-post', ... body='Post body/', ... author=user)
post.save()
```

where you instantiate a new instance named `post` (with a lower-case `p`) and then call save on that instance.

But as I said, in your case, there is no need to call save at all.

Comment: thank you so much. I'm kinda new here so I don't know how everything works here. and I'm still learning. thank you again.

Comment: You should accept the answer as a sign to future searchers that it solved your problem.